# set border to images css

Tags: css

I am trying to set border to an image .. the right, bottom and left border should have the width of 5px and the top border should have 10px.

I tried the following but after defining border-top:10px the upper border disappears completely leaving only the left,right and bottom border there.. any suggestions why this happened and what i should try next?

so here´s my css code that i tried so far:

```
<style>
    #images{
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-top:10px;
}
  </style>
```

Comment: Use border-top-width:10px; instead of border-top.

Comment: thats why im asking.. if you dont want to answer Gowtham then dont post nonsense here

Comment: no offence but http://www.w3schools.com/ would help more in the long run than a copy paste answer. peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
border-top-width:10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
#images {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below css code.

```
border-width: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
```

Comment: @Mike Ok, sounds good. This was just flagged as a low quality post.